# $P\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\xi_{i j k}^2-1\right)\right| \geq n \delta\right\} \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \delta^2}{32+4 \delta}\right) $

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

This concentraion inequality was found when I read a paper about gaussian graphical model. The author gave this result directly.
$$
P\left\{\left|\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\xi_{i j k}^2-1\right)\right| \geq n \delta\right\} \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{n \delta^2}{32+4 \delta}\right) 
$$
where $\xi_{i j k}$'s are independent $N\left(0,1\right)$.
I have checked some materials but I cannot get the value $32+4 \delta$ in the denominator.How did the author obtain this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can rewrite the inequality as
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-n|\geq n\delta) \leq 2\exp\left(-\frac{n\delta^2}{32+4\delta}\right)$$
where $X\sim \chi^2_n$ is a chi-squared distribution. Now we can use the bound from [Massart and Laurent](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-5/Adaptive-estimation-of-a-quadratic-functional-by-model-selection/10.1214/aos/1015957395.full) (Lemma 1 p1325) which says that
$$\mathbb{P}(X-n\geq 2\sqrt{nx}+2x)\leq \exp (-x)$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(n-X\geq 2\sqrt{nx})\leq \exp (-x)$$

Specifically, pick the appropriate values of $x>0$ for each case such that the RHS of the inequality becomes $n\delta$ and show that the resulting bound is better than the one you want to prove. Then, use the union bound (which will give you the factor of $2$).

For example, by picking $x=\frac{n\delta^2}{4}$ on the second inequality you will get
$$\mathbb{P}(n-X\geq n\delta)\leq \exp\left(-\frac{n\delta^2}{4}\right)$$
which is easily seen to be less than $\exp\left(-\frac{n\delta^2}{32+4\delta}\right)$. The second case is similar but requires a bit more calculations.